# Edit an existing cookie in java

Tags: java, cookies

I'm tryng to edit the value of an existing cookie, but in vain. I even tried deleting the cold cookie and creating a new one with new value but even that didnt work. Code snippet for editing a cookie:

```
Cookie modifyCookie= new Cookie(cookie.getName(), newValue)
modifyCookie.setMaxAge(30000)
modifyCookie.setPath("/")
response.addCookie(modifyCookie)
```

Deleting and creating a new one :
//Deleting the old one

```
Cookie oldCookie = new Cookie(cookie.getName(), null)
oldCookie.setMaxAge(0);
oldCookie.setPath("/")
response.addCookie(oldCookie);
```

//Creating a new one

```
Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(newCookieName, newValue
newCookie.setMaxAge(30000)
newCookie.setPath("/")
response.addCookie(newCookie)
```

Neither the existing cookie is getting changed nor the old one is getting deleted and new one is getting created

Can you please tell me what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

@rukavitsya 
Thanks for your inputs.Issue resolved.

The problem was I was adding cookie to response after the response was sent. Hence cookie was not getting reflected in subsequent requests.
I edited the existing cookie in foll way :

```
Cookie oldCookie = new Cookie(cookie.getName(), newValue)
oldCookie.setMaxAge(30000);
oldCookie.setPath("/")
oldCookie.setDomain("domain.com")
response.addCookie(oldCookie);
```

When i edited the cookie before sending the response, things worked as expected.